# How Could I use SQL IN command in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def show_user_events
    user = current_user
    @join_events = JoinEvent.find_all_by_user_id(user.id)
    # @events = Event.where(:id => @join_events)

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # show_user_events.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @events }
    end
end
```

I want to get the specific values ​​in the 'Event'.
The 'event_id' is one of the attributes of the 'JoinEvent'.
Using the 'event_id' values ​​of '@join_events',
I want to get the same effect as the command in the SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE id in (join_events[1].event_id, join_events[2].event_id, ...)
```

What should I do to achieve this effect in rails?

Answer (score 1):

There is at least two ways to do this implicitly or explicitly respectively:

```
JoinEvent.find([1, 2, 3]) # short for JoinEvent.where(id: [1, 2, 3])
JoinEvent.where(event_id: [1, 2, 3])

JoinEvent.where("event_id IN (?)", [1, 2, 3])
```

I prefer first approach when it's possible

Thus in your case you can collect `ids` by:

```
@join_events = JoinEvent.where(user_id: current_user.id)
@join_events_ids = @join_events.pluck(:id)
```

or (more prefered way)

```
current_user.join_event_ids
```

Comes with [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) association

> `collection_singular_ids`
>
> Returns an array of the associated objects’ ids

Comment: If I recall correctly, `pluck` works on `Relation`; not on `Array`. `find_all_by_user_id` will give you an array and `pluck` won't work on that.

Comment: Thank you for your answers :) It has been a great help to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
JoinEvent.where(:event_id => [@join_events.map(&:id)])
```

Comment: With these extra `[]` you will get `[[1, 2]]`. Thus you don't need them

Comment: Thank you for your answers :) It has been a great help to me.